# How to change number field to text field using JS

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I am making the WooCommerce quantity field a text field so it looks nicer but I can't figure out how to make the minus button work.
The plus button works fine, but I have no idea why the minus button is not working, it just does nothing at all.

Maybe someone more experienced with JS can see my problem here?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Containing selector
    var parentSelector = $('.quantity');
    // If it's on the page
    if( parentSelector.length ) {

        // Get the original HTML
        var numberInputs = parentSelector.html();
        // Minus button
        var btnLess = '<button class="minus">-</button>';
        // Change number to text
        var textInputs = numberInputs.replace('type="number"', 'type="text"');
        // Plus button
        var btnMore = '<button class="plus">+</button>';
        // Append it all
        parentSelector.append(btnLess + textInputs + btnMore);
        // Hide the original
        parentSelector.find('input[type="number"]').hide();

        // increase or decrease the count
        $('.plus, .minus').on('click', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var newCounter = $(this).prevAll('input.qty[type="text"]');
            var oldCounter = $(this).prevAll('input.qty[type="number"]');
            var counterVal = newCounter.val();

            if( $(e.target).hasClass('plus') ) {

                counterVal++ ;

            } else {

                counterVal-- ;

            }

            // Apply to both inputs
            newCounter.val(counterVal);
            oldCounter.val(counterVal);

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code is using `prevAll` on the minus button, but the target input appears later in the DOM. `PrevAll` worked fine for the plus button though, since the targeted input comes before the plus button.

The modified code below is tested and working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Containing selector
    var parentSelector = $('.quantity');
    // If it's on the page
    if( parentSelector.length ) {

        // Get the original HTML
        var numberInputs = parentSelector.html();
        // Minus button
        var btnLess = '<button class="minus">-</button>';
        // Change number to text
        var textInputs = numberInputs.replace('type="number"', 'type="text"');
        // Plus button
        var btnMore = '<button class="plus">+</button>';
        // Append it all
        parentSelector.append(btnLess + textInputs + btnMore);
        // Hide the original
        parentSelector.find('input[type="number"]').hide();

        // increase or decrease the count
        $('.plus, .minus').on('click', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            if( $(e.target).hasClass('plus') ) {
              var newCounter = $(this).prevAll('input.qty[type="text"]');
              var oldCounter = $(this).prevAll('input.qty[type="number"]');
              var counterVal = newCounter.val();

              counterVal++ ;

            } else {
              var newCounter = $(this).nextAll('input.qty[type="text"]');
              var oldCounter = $(this).nextAll('input.qty[type="number"]');
              var counterVal = newCounter.val();

              counterVal-- ;
            }

            // Apply to both inputs
            newCounter.val(counterVal);
            oldCounter.val(counterVal);

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You sir are a legend, thank you kindly! @dave-romsey